# there is some error in this recursive binarytree function type

Tags: python, recursion, stack, binary-tree

I tried to check and fix the code but I just can't find what is the problem anywhere with this code

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    
    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)


class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.key = root
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def insert_left(self, new_node):
        if self.left_child == None:
            self.left_child = BinaryTree(new_node)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(new_node)
            t.left_child = self.left_child
            self.left_child = t

    def insert_right(self, new_node):
        if self.right_child == None:
            self.right_child = BinaryTree(new_node)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(new_node)
            t.right_child = self.right_child
            self.right_child = t

    def get_right_child(self):
        return self.right_child

    def get_left_child(self):
        return self.left_child
    
    def set_root_val(self, obj):
        self.key = obj

    def get_root_val(self):
        return self.key

    def preorder(tree):
        if tree:
            print(tree.get_root_val())
            preorder(tree.get_left_child())
            preorder(tree.get_right_child())

    def postorder(tree):
        if tree != None:
            postorder(tree.get_left_child())
            postorder(tree.get_right_child())
            print(tree.get_root_val())

    def inorder(tree):
        if tree != None:
            inorder(tree.get_left_child())
            print(tree.get_root_val())
            inorder(tree.get_right_child())


def build_parse_tree(fp_exp):
    fp_list = fp_exp.split()
    p_stack = Stack()
    e_tree = BinaryTree('')
    p_stack.push(e_tree)
    current_tree = e_tree
    for i in fp_list:
        if i == '(':
            current_tree.insert_left('')
            p_stack.push(current_tree)
            current_tree = current_tree.get_left_child()
        elif i not in ['+', '-', '*', '/', ')']:
            current_tree.set_root_val(int(i))
            parent = p_stack.pop()
            current_tree = parent
        elif i in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
            current_tree.set_root_val(i)
            current_tree.insert_right('')
            p_stack.push(current_tree)
            current_tree = current_tree.get_right_child()
        elif i == ')':
            current_tree = p_stack.pop()
        else:
            raise ValueError
    return e_tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pt = build_parse_tree("( ( 10 + 5 ) * ( 3 - 2 ) )")
    pt.postorder()
```

I run the code and it's return me with this

```
name 'postorder' is not defined
  File "G:\VSCode\PythonVS\BinaryTree6Feb2022.py", line 63, in postorder
    postorder(tree.get_left_child())
  File "G:\VSCode\PythonVS\BinaryTree6Feb2022.py", line 102, in <module>
    pt.postorder()
```

I tried to make it a recursive function but I don't know what am I doing wrong or what might I be missing.
I'm still checking the code but I just can't find missing things

Comment: There are actually quite a few errors but the one you are referencing is because you are missing the `self.` prefix on your method calls, or in your case `tree.`.

Comment: The order functions also do not take `self` as the first argument, and they probably should.

Comment: I didn't even check that, thank for the eye I'll fix it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traversal methods `preorder`, `postorder` and `inorder` have declarations that you would expect for standalone *functions*, but they are indented to be part of the class and so they look like *methods*.

The easiest fix is to move them out of the `class` block and replace the call in your main program with `postorder(pt)`, and it will work.

If you prefer to have them as *methods* on your class, so that you can make the call like `pt.postorder()`, then rename the parameter `tree` to `self` (as that is the common practice), make the recursive calls in method-notation, and move the `if` condition before the recursive calls:

```
    def postorder(self):
        print(self.get_root_val())
        if self.get_left_child():
            self.get_left_child().postorder()
        if self.get_right_child():
            self.get_right_child().postorder()
```

For completeness sake, I provide also an alternative that leaves the `if` condition at the start, but then you must use another syntax on the recursive calls, as you cannot call a method on `None`:

```
    def postorder(self):
        if self:
            print(self.get_root_val())
            BinaryTree.postorder(self.get_left_child())
            BinaryTree.postorder(self.get_right_child())
```

But this is not normal practice in Python.

Comment: Thank you so much for tell me all the thing that I didn't know! I'll fixing all of the order code now! This is so helpful of a information, it's working now!